# Gray blocks in applet menus

Tags: themes, indicator, applet

I've themed my Ubuntu, but now I'm having gray blocks in my applet's menus. For example in the messages applet, battery applet, volume applet and the calendar applet.

It looks like this:

[image: Without selection]
[image: With selection]

I think I'm missing a PNG in the theme folder or a CSS rule, but I've no idea where it could be.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it already.

In `/usr/share/themes/theme/gtk-3.0/gtk-widgets.css`:

```
GtkOrientable {
    background-color: @theme_bg_color;
}
```

Changed it to:

```
GtkOrientable {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Now the gray block is gone and all the menu items are transparent, as it should be.